# Why can't we install UWP ( Powershell script generated during pacakege Creation) with System Account

Tags: uwp

I tried to install my UWP Pacake using the Powershell script generated by VS 2015 .
1 If i open the powershell in Administrator mode and call the script it installs correctly in that machine

2 But if i launch the Powershell in system account it says " Local System account is not allowed to perform this operation."

Do we really need Administrator privilege to install the UWP app? we use SCCM to install the any app in our any client machine? as the current

what is minimim previleage we need to have to install the app in particular machine